# Execution of future package in R results in an endless waiting time

Tags: r, asynchronous, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, future

i have a Problem with the future package. In my Task I try to set up an asynchronous process. I am doing this using Futures. If I run my script for the first time (in a clean RSession) everything is working fine and as expected. Running the same function for the second time, within the same R Session, Ends up in an endless waiting time. The execution stops in the line, where the Futures are started. No Errors are thrown. The Code just runs forever. If I interrupt the Code manually, the browser is called from the line:
Sys.sleep(interval).
Doing this a little bit earlier the call is made from:
Called from: socketSelect(list(con), write = FALSE, timeout = timeout).

I have written a small program, which has basically the same structure as my script and the same Problem occurs. While not obvious in this little example, this structure has some advantage in my original code:

```
 library(future)
library(parallel)

asynchronousfunction <- function(){

 Threads.2.start <- availableCores()
 cl <- parallel::makePSOCKcluster(Threads.2.start)
 plan(cluster, workers = cl)

 threads <- lapply(1:Threads.2.start, function(index){
   future::cluster({Sys.getpid()},persistent = TRUE, workers = cl[[index]])
 })

 while(!any(resolved(threads))){

    Sys.sleep(0.1)

 }

 threads <- lapply(1:Threads.2.start, function(index){
   future::cluster({Sys.getpid()},persistent = TRUE, workers = cl[[index]])
 })

 stopCluster(cl = cl)

}


asynchronousfunction() # First call to the function. Everything is working fine.
asynchronousfunction() #Second call to the function. Endless Execution.
```

I am working on Windows 10 and the R Version is 3.4.2. The package Version is 1.6.2.

I hope you Guys can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Harvard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author `future` here. It looks a like you've tried to overdo it a bit and I am not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve.  Things that looks suspicious to me is your use of:

- `cluster()` - call `future()` instead.
- `cluster(..., workers = cl[[index]])` - don't specify `workers` when you set up a future.
- Is there a reason why you want to use `persistent = TRUE`?
- `resolve(threads)` basically does the same as your `while()` loop.
- You are not collecting the values of the futures, i.e. you're not calling `value()` or `values()`.
- For troubleshooting, you can get more details on what's going on under the hood by setting `option(future.debug = TRUE)`.

If I'd rewrite your example as close to what you have now, a working example would look like this:

```
library("future")

asynchronousfunction <- function() {
  n <- availableCores()
  cl <- makeClusterPSOCK(n)
  plan(cluster, workers = cl)

  fs <- lapply(1:n, function(index) {
    future({ Sys.getpid() }, persistent = TRUE)
  })

  ## Can be replaced by resolve(fs)
  while(!any(resolved(fs))) {
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
  }

  fs <- lapply(1:n, function(index) {
    future({ Sys.getpid() }, persistent = TRUE)
  })

  parallel::stopCluster(cl = cl)
}
```

Instead of rolling your own `lapply()` + `future()`, would it be sufficient for you to use `future_lapply()`?  For example,

```
asynchronousfunction <- function() {
  n <- availableCores()
  cl <- makeClusterPSOCK(n)
  plan(cluster, workers = cl)

  pids <- future_lapply(1:n, function(ii) {
    Sys.getpid()
  })
  str(pids)

  pids <- future_lapply(1:n, function(ii) {
    Sys.getpid()
  })
  str(pids)

  parallel::stopCluster(cl = cl)
}
```

Comment: First thanks for your quick reply. I only had to Change the command makePSOCKCluster to makeClusterPSOCK. I am sorry for the confusion brought up by my small sample Problem. Is there a specific reason to use future instead of cluster? Regarding your second Point, i am trying to build up master-slave scheme, for that it is essential for me to send the function calls to the specific workers. Why is this bad and is there a better way around? I use persistent to maintain the state of the variables in the workers. The Loop is used to let the main process continue if at least one future is resolved.

Comment: I see.  For now, I recommend to you to use the parellel package alone for your needs, e.g. `clusterEvalQ(cl[index], { ... })` (note single `[` - not double `[[`).  Futures are not really designed for targeted workers - at least not yet, cf. https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/issues/172.